# Vector and assignment operator

Tags: c++, vector

I need to do a deep copy of a `vector` to a `vector`. Ex -

```
vector<char> a;
// add some things
vector<char> b;

a = b;
```

I know that I can always say `a(b)` but the problem is I must reassign more than once and to a global variable, so I'm pretty sure I can't use the copy constructor once it's already created.  Is the assignment operator overloaded for `vector`, if not what is the best way to copy a `vector` and all its members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the assignment operator is overloaded for `std::vector` and you can safely use `a = b;`